# Добавление значения переменной в БД

Tags: php, laravel

Переменная `slug` будет содержать ЧПУ, как сохранить ее в БД, если ее значение не будет получено из `view`, а сгенерированно в методе контроллера?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $slug = Slug::make($request->name);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required'
    ]);

    Blog::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('blog.index')
        ->with('success','Successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$slug = Slug::make($request->name);
$request['slug'] = $slug;
```

Answer (score 0):

я думаю проще функционал формирования слуга вынести в модель
как реализовано в некоторых пакетах например

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable

https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Comment: Я использовал https://github.com/ivanlemeshev/laravel5-cyrillic-slug